# Simple app to search for nearby ble, yet got error with mHandler.postDelayed()

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm a starter on Android and BLE and wish to write the Android 4.3 app to communicate with BLE board. I read the simple  and wrote a simple app to search the device.

I set a button to start scan:

```
scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "+++ USER wanna scan +++");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "start scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            scanLeDevice(true); 
        }
    });
```

And then the scanLeDevice method is as below:

```
private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "+++ scan device +++");
    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}
```

The app crashed for NullPointerException. If I comment out mHandler.postDelayed...out, the app can successfully find the ble device. I am new to program and don't know how to debug such a error. Nor do I have any idea about why this runnable goes wrong. Anyone help me out? Thanks so much!

Comment: hi did you found your solution!!!!?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to initialize your Handler (e.g. in your onCreate() Method):

```
mHandler = new Handler();
```